# How to get a list of SharePoint users by pattern name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint API to write an iPhone/iPad client.
The `GetUserCollectionFromSite` method returns all the users. I have searched in MSDN specification:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getusercollectionfromsite.aspx

But apparently there is no way to send a request with something like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetUserCollectionFromSite xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"></GetUserCollectionFromSite>
  <UsersPattern>Ad</UsersPattern>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And a response with user logins matching the pattern "Ad" like Adam, etc..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query for a masked user names. You may only get all the users and filter them on your side.